# Word for someone who has plastic surgery, breast augmentation, etc.?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives, pejorative-language

- She's a ______ beauty.
- My beauty is natural, hers is _________.

Comment: fake + artificial

Comment: If you want to be a bit more subtle in your jab, in your second sentence _acquired_ might fit the bill. (See also _augmented_ , _enhanced_ and _assisted_.)

Comment: Someone once called them "dented-painted" in a sarcastic sense.

Answer (score 4):

The label *plastic* from *plastic surgery* can be used with a derogatory sense in this context:

> **plastic beauty** *noun*
>   1. (uncountable) Beauty achieved by cosmetic surgery.
>   2. A person with such beauty.
>   [- wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plastic_beauty)

Comment: +1 it is the word. I scrolled down to answer and found, you already did :)

Answer (score 3):

My beauty is natural, hers is **fake**!

> not genuine or real; being an imitation of the genuine article

[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/fake)

Answer (score 1):

An *[artificial](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/artificial)* thing is not real or not made of natural things but made to be like something that is real or natural (Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English). For example, you can say 'Her boobs are artificial, but mine are natural'.